# Drawing a rectangle in UIView

Tags: ios, core-graphics

I am trying to draw a transparent rectangle in my UIView which has a black border.

My code however creates a completely black rectangle. Here's my code so far:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    // Drawing code
    CGRect rectangle = CGRectMake(0, 100, 320, 100);
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSetRGBFillColor(context, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.5);
    CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(context, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.5);
    CGContextFillRect(context, rectangle);

}
```

Comment: Change `CGContextFillRect` to `CGContextStrokeRect`

Comment: Same problem. There's just a black rectangle (and it is completely black)

Comment: try with alpha 0.0 in CGContextSetRGBFillColor(context, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.5);

Comment: are you trying to create a transparent see through window with this view? see if this helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11792563/can-a-particular-rect-of-uiview-have-different-alpha/14645130#14645130

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    // Drawing code
    CGRect rectangle = CGRectMake(0, 100, 320, 100);
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSetRGBFillColor(context, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0);   //this is the transparent color
    CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(context, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.5);
    CGContextFillRect(context, rectangle);
    CGContextStrokeRect(context, rectangle);    //this will draw the border

}
```

the effect is like this (backgroundColor is blue)

[image]

Comment: Hmm, its not doing anything. Even when I tried entering some random values for RGB, it just shows a black rectangle everytime.

Comment: @AshishAgarwal you want transparent rectangle , why you entering random values for RGB? look at my drawing

Comment: Well, I am trying to see something other than black. But no luck so far

Comment: @Guo Luchuan:   Can we also set the Alpha property for this rectangle so that this rectangle is 50% transparent ? Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Your code does not require the `CGContextSetRGBFillColor` call and is missing the `CGContextStrokeRect` call. With Swift 5, your final `draw(_:)` implementation should look like this:

```
class CustomView: UIView {

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        backgroundColor = .white
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        guard let ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() else { return }    
        ctx.setStrokeColor(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 0.5)
        let rectangle = CGRect(x: 0, y: 100, width: 320, height: 100)
        ctx.stroke(rectangle)
    }

}
```

---

As an alternative, if your really want to call `CGContextSetRGBFillColor`, you also to have call `CGContextFillRect`. Your final `draw(_:)` implementation would then look like this with Swift 3:

```
class CustomView: UIView {

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        backgroundColor = .white
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        guard let ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() else { return }

        ctx.setFillColor(red: 1, green: 1, blue: 1, alpha: 0)
        ctx.setStrokeColor(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 0.5)

        let rectangle = CGRect(x: 0, y: 100, width: 320, height: 100)
        ctx.fill(rectangle)
        ctx.stroke(rectangle)
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

It will provide the rectangle/square by adjusting values of self frame (customized view or subclass of any class which is inherited from `UIView`) with transparency.

```
[self.layer setBorderWidth:1.0];
[self.layer setBorderColor:[[UIColor colorWithRed:0.10 green:0.45 blue:0.73 alpha:1.0] CGColor]];
[self.layer setCornerRadius:2.0];
[self.layer setShadowOffset:CGSizeMake(-2, -2)];
[self.layer setShadowColor:[[UIColor lightGrayColor] CGColor]];
[self.layer setShadowOpacity:0.5];
```

Comment: Can we also set the Alpha property for this rectangle so that this rectangle is maybe 50% transparent ? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

One handy tip ......

Very often, when you need to draw a square

it's easier to **just draw a 'thick stripe'** .....

```
    let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
    context!.setLineWidth(100)
    context!.setStrokeColor(blah.cgColor)
    context?.move(to: CGPoint(x: 500, y: 200))
    context?.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 500, y: 300))
    context!.strokePath()
```

That will draw a square, which runs downwards from 200 to 300.

It's centered on 500 across, and is 100 wide.

Answer (score 0):

```
CGRect  bounds  = connectorRect;
CGFloat minx = CGRectGetMinX(bounds), midx = CGRectGetMidX(bounds), maxx = CGRectGetMaxX(bounds);
CGFloat miny = CGRectGetMinY(bounds), maxy = CGRectGetMaxY(bounds);
CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [UIColor grayColor].CGColor);
CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 1.0);
CGContextBeginPath(context);
CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context,[UIColor clearColor].CGColor);
CGContextMoveToPoint(context, minx, maxy);
CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, midx, miny);
CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, maxx, maxy);
CGContextClosePath(context);
CGContextDrawPath(context, kCGPathFillStroke);
```

Comment: This is for triangle Dude not for Rectangle